# Why does BeautifulSoup library keeps ignoring Only one specific <TR> element?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

i am trying to pull information about corona cases by countries from worldometers.
For some reason i can not target specific TR Tags by classes (classes on them are just missing in python console but they have it in chrome developer). so i target all of the tr elements and then filter them. everything works fine but for some strange reason CHINA is missing from top 10 countries. Nothing is different about china's html tags but still i cant put it there. any ideas?
'''

```
r = requests.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
all_rows = soup.find_all("tr") 
startingIndex = None

for index,each in enumerate(all_rows,start=0):
    if "World" in each.text: # After that word "WORLD" comes TR elements of individual countries. 
        startingIndex = index
        break

top10 = all_rows[startingIndex+1:startingIndex+11] # here i select top 10 countries that i need.

for index,each in enumerate(top10,start = 1):
    droebiti_list = each.text.split("\n")
    print(f"{index}){droebiti_list[1]} - {droebiti_list[6]}") # and printing info about recovered people
```

.

'''

Comment: China could be censoring the corona cases.

Answer (score 0):

Can't ensure that this code works ('I'm in the wrong environment for this'), but to scrape the data this code should work:

```
r = requests.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
    content = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    all_rows = soup.find_all("tr")

    for elements_all_rows in all_rows: # Like you said this goes trough all 'tr' elements
        ScrapedResult = []
        elements_all_rows = soup.find_all("td") # In each Tr Element you now search for 'td' elements
        for elements_elements_all_rows in elements_all_rows: # Now you go trough the td and filter the text
            ScrapedResult.append(elements_elements_all_rows.getText())
        print(ScrapedResult)
```

you just have to modify the `ScrapedResult` to your needs.

Comment: thing is i need only name of top 10 countries and number of recovered people. this  method will incule all of the TD s from unwatned TR's too.

Answer (score 0):

The page source, the `content` variable, has the countries in a different order than that of the table (the order could be changing because a javascript script or something).

So you can just collect all data and reorder them according to the total cases.

```
import requests,time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Get the page source and clear it
r = requests.get("https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/")
contents = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, "html.parser")
table = soup.find("tbody") 
countries = table.find_all("tr")
startingIndex = None

# Here we will store the top ten countries values
total=list(range(10))
names=list(range(10))
recovered=list(range(10))

# Compare each "new" country with the current top ten
for index,each in enumerate(countries[8:]):
    droebiti_list = each.text.split("\n")
    for j in range(10):
        if int(droebiti_list[2].replace(',','')) > total[j]:

            for jj in reversed(range(j,10)):
                recovered[jj]=recovered[jj-1]
                names[jj]=names[jj-1]
                total[jj]=total[jj-1]

            recovered[j]=droebiti_list[6]
            names[j]=droebiti_list[1]
            total[j]=int(droebiti_list[2].replace(',',''))
            break

    print(f"{index}){droebiti_list[1]} - {droebiti_list[2]}") 

# Print the results    
for k in range(10):
    print(names[k],'\t\t\t',recovered[k])
```

the interesting output:

```
USA              36,254
Spain            64,727
Italy            35,435
France           27,718
Germany              64,300
UK           N/A
China            77,663
Iran             45,983
Turkey           3,957
Belgium              6,707
```